# Bash Expect decrypt password

Tags: openssl, expect

1. I have passphrase in file named phrase which is saved on local system : OXyqRC694pvKQ1FNfIYZQOKS
2. Encrypted my password : 
   echo "ITSMYPASSWORD" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:OXyqRC694pvKQ1FNfIYZQOKS
3. In expect script, I am trying to decrypt the password, before doing scp, but getting error "bad decrypt" while decrypting the password

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect

    set upassword [lindex $argv 0]

    set oF [open "phrase" r]
    set dpassword [read $oF]

    puts $upassword
    puts $dpassword

    puts "echo $upassword | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:$dpassword"
    #if i execute ouput of above line in shell, i am able to decrypt the password, 
    # but below exec command doesnot not work.         

    exec echo $upassword | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:$dpassword
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tcl, the [`read` command](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/read.htm) will include the newline that ends the file. Try this:

```
set dpassword [read -nonewline $oF]
```

Also, the [`exec` command](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) has a `<<` redirection to send a string to the command's stdin:

```
exec openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:$dpassword << $upassword
```

Comment: That did the trick... i was earlier trying to remove newline using sed with echo , but was not working....Thanks